# Problem with lucida in conTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, lucida

I've got a funny problem with Lucida fonts in conTeXt.

Letters shown have an Ascii code decreased by one, but the metrics are the good one. It appears only in text mode.

The minimal example

```
\usetypescript[lucida]
\setupbodyfont[lucida,24pt]
\starttext
abcdefgh

$abcdefgh$
\stoptext
```

shows :

[image]

Other fonts seems to work fine in conTeXt
Lucida fonts work fine in Latex.

Last thing I did was upgrade Manjaro Linux.

I use Linux Manjaro and Context MkIV from standalone installation.
I didn't install MkII context.

Comment: Can you tell use exactly which ConTeXt you have?

Comment: Crosspost on ntg-context https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/087522.html